# Replacing Chrome OS on ASUS C300 for Ubuntu

Tags: asus

I have a Asus C300 and I was wondering if it is possible to uninstall chrome OS and replace it with Ubuntu. If it is possible can I also have some instructions on how to do it.

Comment: I've read another question/answer in which someone (not the one who installed Ubuntu) selected "restore operating system" during startup and the machine reverted to the original version of ChromeOS, *overwriting the entire Ubuntu partition*.  Beware -- these machines are intended to be hard-installed with Chrome and don't play well with removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Well I believe the obvious answer to be Yes, if you have a Bootable USB with Ubuntu on it or an CD. But as mentioned below in the comments It may be harder since it was a chrome book.

For more Info check this question out: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Also, possible duplicate: [How to install Ubuntu 32-bit on Asus C300 chromebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517589/how-to-install-ubuntu-32-bit-on-asus-c300-chromebook)

Comment: Can chrome os be uninstalled????

Comment: Check this serie of videos by TECH BY DMG https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PD8zZiCiiEg

Comment: Possible duplicate you suggest above says it is not possible with Asus 300. The Youtube example uses an Acer C720 not an Asus 300. So the "obvious answer may as well be "No."

Answer (score 1):

John Lewis made a good ROM for this Chromebook. I am currently running Ubuntu Gnome on my C300, but I've used KDE Neon, Kali Linux, and Debian. There are a few issues with the install. I had a huge issue with the touchpad not working, but it has been fixed in the 4.2.0-45 Kernel.

[John Lewis](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/)

Give it a try. Be careful and definitely use the [Chromebook Recovery Utility](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6002417?hl=en).

Oh, and I'm told sound works in most ASUS C300s, but is definitely doesn't work in mine. I think I may have done something wrong, but I really don't want to start over and redo everything.